# CADisplayLink stops updating when UIScrollView scrolled

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-animation

Title is quite self explanatory, but I have some animation being done in a loop triggered by CADisplayLink. However, as soon as I scroll a UIScrollView I have added to my view hierarchy, the animation stops immediately, only to return again when scrolling has completely stopped and come to a standstill....

Anyway to cancel this behaviour?

Comment: Someone should edit the question: the class is CADisplayLink, not UIDisplayLink.

Comment: 2016 - It would seem that **.commonModes** is indeed the solution for typical modern iOS. See: stackoverflow.com/a/4878182/294884 It's quite incredible there has been no QA on this for five years

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run the display link (using `-addToRunLoop:forMode:`) on another thread with another run loop. So create a new thread, create a run loop on that thread, and run the CADisplayLink on that thread/run loop.

Comment: This just reduces UIScrollView stopping, cannot eliminate.

Comment: For 2016: this is actually just wrong, nowadays.  stackoverflow.com/a/4878182/294884

Answer (score 33):

You can also mitigate the effects of this issue by using `NSRunLoopCommonModes` instead of `NSDefaultRunLoopModes`:

```
[displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]
                  forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

Comment: This prevents UIScrollView receiving run-loop call during rendering, finally, stops scrolling at any time.

Comment: This does ***seem to work*** nowadays. The problem Eonil describes seems to have been resolved by Apple.  What a fiasco, Apple.

Comment: This stills fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 7):

Use [`UITrackingRunLoopMode`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Run_Loop_Mode_for_Tracking). It's specifically designed for scrolling stuffs.

Otherwise, just call render & present routine at `-scrollViewDidScroll`.

[UIScrollView broken and halts scrolling with OpenGL rendering (related CADisplayLink, NSRunLoop)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135229/uiscrollview-halted-scrolling-with-opengl-rendering-related-cadisplaylink-nsrun/4135232#4135232)

Comment: For the record, in 2016 this just doesn't work on all the devices we tested. This seems to be a solution: stackoverflow.com/a/4878182/294884

Answer (score 4):

Here you can find a better (and more complex) solution:

[Animation in OpenGL ES view freezes when UIScrollView is dragged on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876488/animation-in-opengl-es-view-freezes-when-uiscrollview-is-dragged-on-iphone)

that allows you to use 'NSRunLoopCommonModes' and avoids OpenGL freezing when holding a finger without scrolling.

This is related to what Doug found (setting the frame interval of CADisplayLink to 2 instead of 1 fixing UIScrollView).

Answer (score 4):

Actually CADisplayLink support multiple RunloopMode.
try this:

```
    [displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:UITrackingRunLoopMode];
    [displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

Answer (score 2):

NSRunLoopCommonModes seems to mess with the bounciness and continuous nature of the uiscrollview.

Answer (score 1):

I found that if I set the frame interval to 2 instead of 1 (so 30 frames a second) everything works fine.  So what I'm doing is setting it to 2 when my popover comes up and resetting it to 1 when it dismisses.

Answer (score 1):

We fixed this same issue by changing the `frameInterval` from 1, to 2. This essentially halves the rendering rate of your OpenGL scene, but it still may render sufficiently for your needs.

> frameInterval 
>   The number of frames that must pass before the display
>   link notifies the target again.
>
> @property(nonatomic) NSInteger frameInterval Discussion The default
>   value is 1, which results in your application being notified at the
>   refresh rate of the display. If the value is set to a value larger
>   than 1, the display link notifies your application at a fraction of
>   the native refresh rate. For example, setting the interval to 2 causes
>   the display link to fire every other frame, providing half the frame
>   rate.
>
> Setting this value to less than 1 results in undefined behavior and is
>   a programmer error.

Comment: How in the world does this resolve the error? The problem seems to be that animation stops. How does halving the frame rate make it run again? This would seem to be a case where 0/2=0.

Comment: @OldPeculier since the display link will fire every other frame, we are able to free up CPU time for other system tasks, such as rendering the scroll view. Try it.

Comment: You're saying that CADisplayLink is not firing its callback because the CPU is overloaded, and that by halving the number of callbacks this lightens the CPU load such that the callback is executed. I find that...surprising.