# UIScrollView broken and halts scrolling with OpenGL rendering (related CADisplayLink, NSRunLoop)

Tags: ios, opengl-es, uiscrollview, scroll, cadisplaylink

Solution note, Not a question.

`UIScrollView` suspends OpenGL rendering by preventing firing `CADisplayLink` tick when `CADisplayLink` registered with `NSDefaultRunLoopMode`.

But, if you use `NSRunLoopCommonModes` to solve this, `UIScrollView` will halt scrolling at burst scrolling. And after once halted, it does not scroll again. (broken)

And registering CADisplayLink in other thread/runloop (as described in answer of this question: [CADisplayLink stops updating when UIScrollView scrolled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524347/cadisplaylink-stops-updating-when-uiscrollview-scrolled/4135266#4135266)) reduces UIScrollView behavior breaking, but cannot eliminate.

Comment: stackoverflow.com/a/4878182/294884 seems to work in 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`UITrackingRunLoopMode`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Run_Loop_Mode_for_Tracking). It's specifically designed for scrolling stuffs.

Otherwise, call render & present code at `-scrollViewDidScroll` too, not only in `CADisplayLink`'s tick callback.

Comment: This will partially work. scrollViewDidScroll: is only called when the scrolling actually moves. If you start a scroll, then hold still without lifting a finger, the render will not be called.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem as Matt. Any solution to this issue?