# Trying to wait on group of NSURLConnections to complete

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, grand-central-dispatch

I've got a bunch of server requests which I can run asynchronously, but I need to wait for them all to finish before I continue.

dispatch_group_async and it seems quite reasonable, but I can't get it to work. It either blocks forever or doesn't block at all. My latest attempt looks something like....

```
dispatch_group_t group;

- (void)cleanRoom {
    NSAssert(![NSThread isMainThread], @"not on main thread.");
    group = dispatch_group_create();

    for (Junk *thing in myRoom) {
    // take it off the current thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            // register code against group
            dispatch_group_enter(attachmentGroup);
            NSURLConnectionWrapper *wrapper = [[NSURLConnectionWrapper alloc] init];
            wrapper.delegate = self;
            [wrapper sendRequestFor:thing];
        }];
    }

    // wait till the stuff is the group is done
    dispatch_group_wait(attachmentGroup, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    NSLog(@"waiting complete!!!!");

    // process the results now that I have them all
}

- (void)wrapperConnectionDone {
    // do a bit more junk
    dispatch_group_leave(group);
}
```

This causes it to block forever because `NSURLConnectionDelegate` and `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` methods are never getting called. I'm assume I've somehow block their thread, but using `NSLog` I can confirm the `NSURLConnection` is on a different thread than my `cleanRoom` method.

I read a bit about other threads not having run loops to make the callbacks, so I've tried things like `connection setDelegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]]` and `[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate distantFuture]]` but to no noticable effect.

`+ sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` doesn't work for me, I've got some ugly authentication. I've seen some good example with that, but I've failed at adapting.

I'm obviously missing some fundamental bit, but I can't find it.

Comment: I've been using NSOperations to do this, and when the queue goes to 0 you know you are done. A really easy to use easy to employ set of code - a operations manager and a sample NSOperation subclass, can be found here: github.com/dhoerl/NSOperation-WebFetches-MadeEasy. There is a "How-To" in OperationsRunner.h That said there are many of these on github.

Comment: You have an excellent point. Earlier I had a more simplified code with `setDelegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]]` on my `NSURLConnection` instead of creating a extra GCD block in the calling code. Now that I have things working with GCD, I might go back and switch it back for easier readability. In many cases NSOperation and GCD can be used to do the same thing. For others who might follow, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373331/nsoperation-vs-grand-central-dispatch was quite descriptive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSURLConnection` needs to run on a thread with a processed run-loop. The simplest such thread is the main thread. So just `dispatch_async` these connection creations to `dispatch_get_main_queue()` and the rest of your `dispatch_group` logic should be fine. Keep in mind that the delegate methods will be called on the main thread (from the `NSURLConnection` Overview):

> These delegate methods are called on the thread that started the asynchronous load operation for the associated NSURLConnection object.

Comment: Great, it's working. It turned out to be a compound problem. I had unwittingly block my main thread in another process so `NSURLConnectionDelegate` calls weren't being made even when I put them on the main thread with the run loop. You answer solved the one issue and let me look in the right place for the other.