# iOS: How to do hard work with data in background thread?

Tags: ios, multithreading

I have a method like:

```
- (BOOL)shouldDoSomeWork {
   BOOL result = // here I need do hard work with data in background thread and return result, so main thread should wait until the data is calculated and then return result;
   return result;
}
```

How to implement that?

Comment: If you want to process something in the background, you can't return the result like this. You'll have to use a delegate or blocks (like an anonymous function).

Comment: You say that you want the main thread to wait on this new thread. If it does that, there's no point in making a thread. Just use the method as you have it here.

Comment: The reason of this is that I want to start activityIndicator, and then do some hard work. If to do hard work on main thread, activity Indicator do not want to be visible

Comment: @Jim Any GUI interaction (such as starting the activity indicator) has to be done on the main thread. You should go with James's method, and at the end call [self performSelectorOnMainThread..] and pass the result using this method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking for this:

```
-(void) startWork
{ 
    //Show activity indicator
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(doSomeWork) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}

-(void) doSomeWork
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];
    //Do your work here
    [pool release];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(doneWork) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}  

-(void) doneWork
{
   //Hide activity indicator  
}
```

Comment: If you want the main thread to wait on this thread, don't use a thread

Comment: no! NSThread is not the way to go! Look into NSOperationQueue or grand central dispatch

Comment: If you have an alternate solution, feel free to add to this answer or post your own. =]

Comment: @Jim I've added a more complete solution for including activity indicators.

Answer (score 5):

Example how to do it with GCD:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        // Your hard code here
        // ...

        //BOOL result = ...

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
            [self callbackWithResult:result];  // Call some method and pass the result back to main thread
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

[Common](http://eschatologist.net/blog/?p=232) [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373331/nsoperation-vs-grand-central-dispatch) is to use the highest level of abstraction available to you to perform a task. As such `NSThread` should be relatively low down in the list of things you can do to execute work in the background.

The order you investigate APIs should be like this:

1. [NSOperation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004591) / [NSOperationQueue](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html)
2. [Grand Central Dispatch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) (libdispatch)
3. NSThread
4. POSIX threads

With the first two you write your code as a "unit of work" and then put this work on a queue to be executed at some point. The system takes care of creating and destroying threads for you and the APIs are easy to work with. Here's an example using `NSOperationQueue`.

```
NSBlockOperation * blockOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    //Do work


    //update your UI on the main thread.
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(workDone:) withObject:workResults waitUntilDone:NO];
}];

[self.operationQueue addOperation:blockOperation];
```

easy as that.

Answer (score 1):

That's not typically how you would do it. You need something structured more like this:

```
- (void)doSomeWorkAndThen:(^void)block {
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^ {
    // do
    // some
    // work
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
      block();
    });
  });
```

That is, you keep the request and what you do afterwards in one place.

Comment: which is fine until you pass NULL for the completion block. Your code could be made better by following platform naming conventions, e.g. `-(void)doSomeWorkWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completion;`

Comment: Absolutely, I was intending to show the structure rather than providing code to copy and paste...