# Default value of maxConcurrentOperationCount for NSOperationQueue

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

As the title suggests, what is the default value of the maxConcurrentOperationCount for NSOperationQueue?

Is it set to a value of 1?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOperationQueue/maxConcurrentOperationCount),

> The maximum number of concurrent operations set explicitly on the
>   receiver using the setMaxConcurrentOperationCount: method. **If no value
>   has been explicitly set, this method returns
>   NSOperationQueueDefaultMaxConcurrentOperationCount by default**.

So it is `NSOperationQueueDefaultMaxConcurrentOperationCount`. If this is set, it will choose an appropriate value based on the number of available processors and other relevant factors.

This is how [it is defined](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/NSOperationQueue_class.pdf):

```
enum {
  NSOperationQueueDefaultMaxConcurrentOperationCount = -1
};
```

> **NSOperationQueueDefaultMaxConcurrentOperationCount:** The
>   default maximum number of operations is determined dynamically by the
>   NSOperationQueue object based on current system conditions.

Comment: meaning to say the NSOperationQueueDefaultMaxConcurrentOperationCount is not fixed right?

Comment: It depends on the system conditions, that is what documentation states. So it will choose an appropriate value based on that.

Comment: So that it can be dynamically determined. Normally a count wont have a value as -1 and this can be used to check if it needs to dynamically find out the required count. Check this for more details https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/NSOperationQueue_class.pdf

Comment: correct me if I am wrong. 0 and above means it is static and -1 is dynamic. Am i right?

Comment: If you set it as 0 or more, it will take that value. But if you set it as NSOperationQueueDefaultMaxConcurrentOperationCount, it will try to get it dynamically.

Comment: Do you know any way to retrieve that dynamically determined value at runtime ?

Comment: There is no way to do that. The kernel determines it, and by the time it told you, it could easily have changed again.

Answer (score 4):

In one of my apps, I add about 35k instances of `NSOperation` to an `NSOperationQueue` at once. If I set `maxConcurrentOperationCount` to 64, I gain about 20x of performance compared to the default value. The CPU load rises from ~120% to 400% which seems to indicate that the default value is so high that the CPU is mostly busy working on the op queue overhead.

Conclusion: if you have many short lived `NSOperation` it might be worth to play with the `maxConcurrentOperationCount`.

Answer (score 4):

## `maxConcurrentOperationCount` of `NSOperationQueue` can only set from 1 to 6 on iPhone Platform .

It is not a good idea to set `maxConcurrentOperationCount` of `NSOperationQueue` as default value. As it means an unlimited number of queues.

### When should the `maxConcurrentOperationCount` of `NSOperationQueue`  be set from 1 to 6 ?

When multiple tasks can be invoked simultaneously,   the `maxConcurrentOperationCount` of `NSOperationQueue` should be set as 6.
For example, multiple images can be downloaded at the same time.

Why is it six specifically instead of 10 or 100?

In the framework named `SDWebImage` , we can see the source code as follows:

```
- (instancetype)init {
   self = [super init];
   if (self) {
       _maxConcurrentDownloads = 6;
       _downloadTimeout = 15.0;
       _executionOrder = SDWebImageDownloaderFIFOExecutionOrder;
       _acceptableStatusCodes = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(200, 100)];
   }
   return self;
}
```

This code means that the default value is 6.
[SDWebImage Reference  SDWebImageDownloaderConfig Class Reference](https://sdwebimage.github.io/SDWebImage/Classes/SDWebImageDownloaderConfig.html#/c:objc(cs)SDWebImageDownloaderConfig(py)maxConcurrentDownloads)

the meaning of  `maxConcurrentDownloads` is same as `maxConcurrentOperationCount` ([Apple-Docs-NSOperationQueue-maxConcurrentOperationCount](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsoperationqueue/1414982-maxconcurrentoperationcount) )

Why is it six specifically instead of 10 or 100?

The coder of `SDWebImage`  said it is via experimentation:

Reference: [Why SDWebImageDownloader maxConcurrentOperationCount = 6? #1961](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage/issues/1961)

Neglect the experimentation, and the `maxConcurrentOperationCount` of `NSOperationQueue`  should be set from 1 to 6 because the maximum number of processor cores on the iOS platform is six from iPhone to iPhone 14 /14 Pro/14 Pro Max.

| iPhone | First released | system on | number of processor cores |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| iPhone | 2007 | S (Samsung S5L8900) | 1 core |
| iPhone 3G | 2008 | S (Samsung S5L8900) | 1 core |
| iPhone 3GS | 2009 | S (Samsung S5PC100 | 1 core |
| iPhone 4 | 2010 | A4 | 1 core |
| iPhone 4S | 2011 | A5 | 2 cores |
| iPhone 5 | 2012 | A6 | 2 cores |
| iPhone 5S | 2013 | A7 | 2cores |
| iPhone 6/6 plus | 2014 | A8 | 2 cores |
| iPhone 6s/6s plus/SE | 2015 | A9 | 2 cores |
| iPhone 7/plus | 2016 | A9 | 4 cores (2 cores used) |
| iPhone 8/plus/X | 2017 | A11 | 6 cores = 2 high power Monsoon cores + 4 low power Mistral cores |
| iPhone XS/XS MAX/XR | 2018 | A12 | 6 cores = 2 high power Vortex cores + 4 low power Tempest cores |
| iPhone 11 /11 Pro/11 Pro Max | 2019 | A13 | 6 cores = 2 performance + 4 efficiency cores |
| iPhone 12 /12 Pro/12 Pro Max | 2020 | A14 | 6 cores = 2 performance + 4 efficiency cores |
| iPhone 13 /13 Pro/13 Pro Max | 2021 | A15 | 6 cores = 2 performance + 4 efficiency cores |
| iPhone 14 /14 Pro/14 Pro Max | 2022 | A15 | 6 cores = 2 performance + 4 efficiency cores |

We can print the number of processor cores with the code as follows:

```
   NSUInteger cpuCoresCount = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] processorCount];
```

We can print the number of active processor cores with the code as follows:

```
   NSUInteger activeCPUCoresCount = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] activeProcessorCount];
```

Reference Docs: [Apple-Docs-NSProcessInfo-processorCount](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsprocessinfo/1415622-processorcount)

It is reasonable to set  `_maxConcurrentDownloads` on the iPhone Platform as the count of CPU cores. As for the further comment, `activeProcessorCount` may be better.

In the framework named `YYKit`, `queueCount` is set as `activeProcessorCount`.

```
#define MAX_QUEUE_COUNT 16
   static int queueCount;
   static dispatch_queue_t queues[MAX_QUEUE_COUNT];
   static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
   static int32_t counter = 0;
   dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
       queueCount = (int)[NSProcessInfo processInfo].activeProcessorCount;
       queueCount = queueCount < 1 ? 1 : queueCount > MAX_QUEUE_COUNT ? MAX_QUEUE_COUNT : queueCount;
       if ([UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion.floatValue >= 8.0) {
           for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < queueCount; i++) {
               dispatch_queue_attr_t attr = dispatch_queue_attr_make_with_qos_class(DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL, QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0);
               queues[i] = dispatch_queue_create("com.ibireme.yykit.render", attr);
           }
       } else {
           for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < queueCount; i++) {
               queues[i] = dispatch_queue_create("com.ibireme.yykit.render", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
               dispatch_set_target_queue(queues[i], dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0));
           }
       }
   });
   int32_t cur = OSAtomicIncrement32(&counter);
   if (cur < 0) cur = -cur;
   return queues[(cur) % queueCount];
#undef MAX_QUEUE_COUNT
```

### When should the `maxConcurrentOperationCount` of `NSOperationQueue`  be set as 1 ?

They are setting `maxConcurrentOperationCount` as one means that only one task can be invoked simultaneously.

When only one task can be invoked simultaneously,  `maxConcurrentOperationCount` should be set as 1.
For example, only one GIF image can be animated simultaneously; only one video can be played at the same time. In addition, only one video/image can be decoded simultaneously.

Reference: [Apple-Docs-NSOperationQueue-maxConcurrentOperationCount](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsoperationqueue/1414982-maxconcurrentoperationcount)