# php mysql post from xcode is limited to around 41

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, reporting-services, nsurlconnection

In my iPad app, I am getting reports that the user can input. Ones he is done with the reports he can send them to the server. I am using HTTP Post for this and I have a php web service that is receiving the data. For each report send, the php give feedback that the information was correctly stored in mysql.

I am facing the issue that the user can only send around 41 reports, after that the php is not responding to the reports send. After waiting some time, around 20-30 minutes, the user is once again able to send reports, until getting to the limit of the 41 reports.

What need to be changed in php.ini or mysql that the user can send all reports without the before mentioned issue.

---

I am using this code for iOS and sending each report one after the other.

```
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
NSString *data = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"uniqueID=%@&fecha=%@&numID=%@&rep=%@&hosp=%@&folio=%@&diagnostico=%@&tratamiento=%@&dosis=%@&quimio=%@&medico=%@", uniqueID, strFecha, strNumID, info.rep, info.hosp, info.folio, info.diagnostico, info.tratamiento, strDosis, info.quimio, info.medico];
iLoop = iLoop + 1;
NSLog(@"data: %d", iLoop);
[body appendData:[data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSURLConnection *conn=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Comment: In your delegate, did you implement `connection:didFailWithError:`? What does it report?

Answer (score 0):

One of two problems are possible.

1. #### Client-side limitations:

   Generally, you would want to constrain how many concurrent uploads you are performing. `NSURLConnection` imposes limits itself, and if you initiate too many, you risk having some of the latter ones time out.

   The typical solution to this problem is to (a) create an `NSOperationQueue` with a `maxConcurrentOperationCount` of 3 or 4; (b) wrap the upload in an `NSOperation`.  Using AFNetworking makes this process very simple.

   If you're going to do it yourself, you can wrap your delegate-based `NSURLConnection` in a concurrent `NSOperation` subclass as [Dave Dribin describes](http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2009/05/05/concurrent_operations/) (though I might suggest making it cancelable, as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22261167/1271826)).

   I'd heartily suggest you consider using AFNetworking (which wraps the network requests in operations) and make sure you specify `maxConcurrentOperationCount` of 3 or 4.

   By the way, I'd make sure you implement `connection:didFailWithError:`, and update your question with the reported `NSError`. That will help diagnose what the problem is.
2. #### Server-side limitations:

   You describe some manifestations of the problem (notably, having to wait 20-30 minutes), which is not consistent with client-side issues. Is it possible that the server is enforcing some criteria?

   If there really is some server limitation (which I find unlikely), you should go to the author of the server code and identify the precisely limitations/guidelines. Then you can develop the client code accordingly.

Personally, I'd be more inclined to suspect the first point and it seems like you should do that, anyway. You never want to initiate too many concurrent requests.