# Replacing NSURLConnection with NSURLSession

Tags: ios, nsurlsession

I have been starting a design for `NetworkCommunication`. I had a design where `NSOperation` subclasses create and manage their own `NSURLConnection`. The `NSOperation` subclass is instantiated by a `NetworkManger` class which adds it to the `NSOperationQueue`. Once the request is finished the delegate(ex:`ViewController` will be called). This is the flow:

The Network Manger instantiates `NSOperation` subclass (which encapsulates URL, parameters etc) and adds it to a `NSOperationQueue` it maintains.
NSOperation subclass instantiates `NSURLConnection` (which performs `asynchronous` request and retrieves data)
`NSURLConnection` dumps data to NSOperation-subclass
NSOperation-subclass executes the completion block supplied by the delegate( view controller).
I'm trying to implement the same pattern with `NSURLSession` now. I want to be able to encapsulate the url and parameters required to make a network request inside a single object.

Is it fine if i use the same pattern if I use `NSURLSession`. I checked `AFNetworking` classes. But, they have not subclassed NSOperation for `NSURLSession`. And, moreover where should the session object go. Will it be a part of the NSOperation class.

Can someone give some expert advice on this. I should be able to cancel requests, do uploading(POST/PUT), downloading of data. The Network Manager class would be the single point of contact for any network request.

Comment: @Bhavesh Nai, please do not add 'thanks in advance' or other salutations to the end of your edits, they are regarded as 'noise' http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: Can someone answer this question pls rather than just only editing. Are there no iOS experts here?PLs help

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Update:

`NSURLConnection` is deprecated effective Mac OS 10.11 and iOS 9. So, at this point `NSURLSession` should be used in lieu of `NSURLConnection`. As the `NSURLConnection.h` header says:

> **Deprecated:** The `NSURLConnection` class should no longer be used. `NSURLSession` is the replacement for `NSURLConnection`.

My original answer is below.

---

The answer depends upon whether you need the richness of the various `NSURLSession` delegate methods or not. If you're ok using the completion block renditions (i.e. no progress callbacks, no streaming, etc.), the conversion from `NSURLConnection` to `NSURLSession` is pretty trivial. Just put your `NSURLSession` instance in your `NetworkManager` class, and then wrap the delegate based `NSURLSessionTask` instances in a concurrent `NSOperation` subclass and you're done. Just adopt the standard asynchronous/concurrent `NSOperation` subclass pattern.

If you're using the delegate-based renditions of `NSURLSession`, it's a whole different kettle of fish. The main hassle is that the various `NSURLSessionTask` delegate methods are called on the session `delegate` rather than a task delegate object. At first blush, this might sound like it's a trivial issue, but if your operation instances have unique completion/progress blocks, for example, you're stuck with the hassle of how to have the session object map these delegate method callbacks to the individual original request operation instances.

To tackle this, you have to maintain a mapping of task identifiers to your `NSOperation` subclass objects. You can then implement these `NSURLSessionTask` (including task, download task, and upload task) delegate methods at the respective `NSOperation` subclass. The `NSURLSession` network manager class can then, when it receives a `NSURLSessionTask` delegate call, use the task identifier to identify the appropriate `NSOperation` instance, and then call the appropriate delegate method there.

Finally, if you intend to handle background `NSURLSession` instances, life gets even more difficult (because background tasks will continue even after your app has terminated and all of its objects have been discarded). Background sessions simply don't lend themselves to an `NSOperation`-based approach.

Bottom line, this is trivial if you only need the completion-block `NSURLSession` methods, but it's a bit of a hassle if you need the delegate-based rendition.

Comment: Thanks Rob. This is my understanding now: If we are going for a block based approach, NSOperation is fine. But, if we are going for a delegate based approach then we have to manage the tasks. My doubt is: If I have the NSOperation subclass implement the task level delegate methods, what is the issue. Please explain.Am not getting that.

Comment: @user694688 I'm not saying you cannot use operation-based approach for delegate-based `NSURLSession`, but rather simply that it takes more work.

Comment: For example, let's say you have two network requests, wrapped in their own operations, one which is downloading an image and one that is requesting JSON. When the `NSURLSession` has its delegate called for the task delegate methods, how does it know for which operation (the image or the JSON) that call is intended? There are two logical approaches: One is to have a separate session for each operation (which seems architecturally inelegant). The other is to have the common session instance maintain a mapping of which task identifier belongs to which operation.

Comment: Rob - Thanks i understood this. What is the best way to approach this so implementation is scalable. And, why are task level delegates implemented at the session level. Right now, i have two classes, Network Manager and NetworkOperation(subclass of NSOperation).NetworkManager class has a NSOperationQueue to which for each request i create the NetworkOpertion class and add it. How should i change this for NSURLSession.

Comment: @user694688 Why are task delegates implemented at session level? I don't know Apple's precise thought process, but if I were to guess, it's possibly to come up with a design compatible with tasks added to a background session, where the app can be terminated and then restarted when the downloads finish. You can easily re-instantiate the session manager delegate, but it would be really hard to re-instantiate the individual task delegates. Having said that, it's a bone-headed design, IMHO (that, plus the failure to give us a `userInfo` object).

Comment: In terms of the right design given these constraints, if you need the delegate rendition of `NSURLSession`, then I'd be inclined to implement it as I outlined in the third paragraph of my above answer. It's more complicated than the block-based solution, but offers greater flexibility and control for the future.

Comment: Am not getting this statement:"The NSURLSession network manager class can then, when it receives a NSURLSessionTask delegate call". According to you, the NSOperation subclass will implement the delegate methods. But how will NetworkManager class get a delegate call then. Sorry if i have misunderstood anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55333/discussion-between-rob-and-user694688).