# What is the difference between dispatch_queue and NSOperationQueue?

Tags: ios, swift, concurrency, nsoperationqueue, dispatch-async

I want to understand difference between dispath_queue and NSOperationQueue, when I can to write my code as:

```
let queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
    dispatch_async(queue) { () -> Void in

        let img1 = Downloader.downloadImageWithURL(imageURLs[0])
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.imageView1.image = img1
        })

    }
```

and as:

```
queue = NSOperationQueue()

queue.addOperationWithBlock { () -> Void in
    let img4 = Downloader.downloadImageWithURL(imageURLs[3])

    NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({
        self.imageView4.image = img4
    })

}
```

So, what is the difference between these 2 blocks? If it's possible, describe it for me, please

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373331/nsoperation-vs-grand-central-dispatch

Comment: `NSOperationQueue` has extra features that are sometimes useful, such as cancellation and being able to look at the operation count.

Comment: Please search your query before putting a new question. Thanks.

Comment: @PhillipMills so it does not matter what I will use, yes? They have the same effect?