# 2017 / Swift 3.1 - GCD vs NSOperation

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperation

I am diving a bit deeper into concurrency and have been reading extensively about GCD and `NSOperation`. However, a lot of posts like the canonic [answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373331/nsoperation-vs-grand-central-dispatch) are several years old.

It seemed to me that `NSOperation` main advantages used to be, *at the cost of some performance*:

- "the way to go" generally for more than a simple dispatch as the highest level abstraction (built atop of GCD)
- to make task manipulation (cancellation, etc.) a lot easier
- to easily set up dependencies between tasks

Given GCD's `DispatchWorkItem` & block cancellation / `DispatchGroup` / `qos` in particular,  is there really an incentive (cost-performance wise) to use `NSOperation` anymore for concurrency apart from cases where you need to be able to cancel a task when it began executing or query the task state ?

Apple seems to put a lot more emphasis on GCD, at least in their WWDC (granted it's more recent than `NSOperation`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see them each still having their own purpose. I just recently rewatched the 2015 WWDC talk about this (Advanced NSOperations), and I see two main points here.

**Run Time & User Interaction**

From the talk:

> NSOperations run for a little bit longer than you would expect a block to run, so blocks usually take a few nanoseconds, maybe at most a millisecond, to execute.
>
> NSOperations, on the other hand, can be much longer, for anywhere from a couple of milliseconds to even several minutes

The example they talk about is in the WWDC app, where there exists an NSOperation that has a dependency on having a logged in user. The dependency NSOperation presents a login view controller and waits for the user to authenticate. Once finished, that NSOperation finishes and the NSOperationQueue resumes it's work. I don't think you'd want to use GCD for this scenario.

**Subclassing**

Since NSOperations are just classes, you can subclass them to get more reusability out of them. This isn't possible with GCD.

Example: (Using the WWDC login scenario from above)

You have many NSOperations in your code base that are associated with a user interaction that requires them to be authenticated. (Liking a video, in this example.) You could extend NSOperation to create an AuthenticatedOperation, then have all those NSOperations extend this new class.

Answer (score 2):

First off, `NSOperationQueue` let you enqueue *operations*, that is, some sort of asynchronous operations with a `start` method, a `cancel` method and a few observable properties, while with a dispatch queue one can submit a *block* or a *closure* or a *function* to a dispatch queue, which will be then executed.

An "Operation" is semantically fundamentally different than a block (or closure, function). An operation has an underlying asynchronous task, while a block (closure or functions) is just that.

What comes close to an `NSOperation`, though, is an *asynchronous* function, e.g.:

```
func asyncTask(param: Param, completion: (T?, Error?) ->())
```

Now with *Futures* we can define the same asynchronous function like:

```
func asyncTask(param: Param) -> Future<T>
```

which makes such asynchronous functions quite handy.

Since futures have combinator functions like `map` and `flatMap` and so on, we can quite easily "emulate" the "dependency" feature of `NSOperation`, just in a more powerful, more concise and more comprehensible way.

We can also implement some sort of `NSOperationQueue` with a few lines of code based solely on GCD, say a "TaskQueue" and with basically the same features, like "maxConcurrentTasks" and can use it to enqueue *task functions* (not operations), in just a more powerful, more concise and a more comprehensible way as well.  ;)

In order to get a cancelable operation, you need to create a subclass of `NSOperation` - while you can create a async function "ad-hod" - inline.

Also, since *cancellation* is an independent concept, we can assume, that there exists some library whose implementation is solely based on GCD which solves this problem in the, uhm, the usual way ;)   It may look like this:

```
self.cancellationRequest = CancellationRequest()
self.asyncTask(param: param, cancellationToken: cr.token).map { result in
   ...
}
```

and later:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: animated) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.cancellationRequest.cancel() 
}
```

So, IMHO there's really no reason to use clunky `NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue`, and there's no reason any more for subclassing  `NSOperation`, which is quite elaborate and surprising difficult, unless you don't care about data races.