# NSoperation vs Dispatch_async for Web Socket Handle

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am using socketio for network response call in my iPhone app. The data can came on anytime and is heavy data.

Sometime my app get hang and fliker a lot of new data comesup.

So which method or API or things to use in app. NSOperation queue or the Dispatch_async methods. Any suggetions please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373331/nsoperation-vs-grand-central-dispatch

Comment: @PiyushPatel  I am looking for WEbSocket based API. for the Socket io , ON calls.

Comment: looking for https://github.com/elabs/mobile-websocket-example  & https://github.com/facebook/SocketRocket  ?