# UIScrollView randomly stuck, CADisplayLink not firing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, opengl-es

I have an OpenGLES app, with a CADisplayLink (added in NSRunLoopCommonModes) that I use to call the main loop (where I do all the OpenGL calls).

I added a UIScrollView, but it randomly get stuck. If I send the app to the background, when I get back sometimes it works perfectly, while others it's stuck (I can sort of move it around, but it doesn't slide when you let go).

Tracking down the problem, I noticed the UIScrollView's internal funcion _*smoothScrollWithUpdateTime*: is not being called. Apparently it uses is own CADisplayLink to get that call.
So I tried adding my own CADisplayLink (separate from the main one that does all the drawing), and it's also randomly not being called. Here is the code:

```
- (void) addDisplayLink
{
    displayLink = [NSClassFromString(@"CADisplayLink") displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(loop:)];
    [displayLink setFrameInterval:1];
    [displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}

- (void) loop:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Loop working!");
}
```

Any ideas?

**TL/DR:** I have two CADisplayLinks and one of them is not working.

Comment: It seems this only happens if I actually draw something in my main loop, commenting out the swap buffers line ([context_ presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES]) 'fixes' the problem. Of course not drawing anything is not an acceptable solution!

Comment: This sounds like a related issue to what's described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944050/cadisplaylink-opengl-rendering-breaks-uiscrollview-behaviour . My suggestion there to move your rendering to a background queue might also help you here.

Comment: @BradLarson - Thanks, so if I understand your post correctly, the reason my second DisplayLink is not being called is because it takes too long for the first one to process a frame? I'm doing very little, and it takes only 6ms to process a frame (3ms CPU, 3ms GPU according to the debugger, running at 60 fps without problems). Is that enough to break it?

Comment: If everything's running on the main thread, your OpenGL ES rendering may be taking just long enough to disrupt the scrolling timer. I know that I saw some odd artifacts there before I moved all of my rendering to a background queue.