# openGL ES warnings

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm using openGL ES to display a YUV420 video on a `UIView`. I'm following this thread ([CADisplayLink OpenGL rendering breaks UIScrollView behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944050/cadisplaylink-opengl-rendering-breaks-uiscrollview-behaviour/5956119#5956119)) to achieve a 30fps. Everything seems to be okay. The playback is smooth. Now thought I running my app through Instruments and I get few warnings:

1. Logical Buffer Load - Summary => slow framebuffer load
2. GPU Wait on Texture - Summary => CPU wait for GPU on Texture Upload
3. Texture Upload Non-Optimal GPU Utilization - Summary => Mid-frame texture upload

In my callback I do the following:

```
[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:_context];
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

// load the color components into OpenGL
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _textures[TEXTURE_Y]);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, frameWidth, frameHeight, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (UInt8*)yuvFrame.luma.bytes);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _textures[TEXTURE_U]);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, frameWidth/2, frameHeight/2, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (UInt8*)yuvFrame.chromaB.bytes);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _textures[TEXTURE_V]);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, frameWidth/2, frameHeight/2, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (UInt8*)yuvFrame.chromaR.bytes);

// draw
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, sizeof(indices)/sizeof(indices[0]), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
[_context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
```

And prior to this call, in the `init` method of the `UIView`, I generate the textures and set some params, like this:

```
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);

glGenTextures(NUM_TEXTURES, _textures);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _textures[TEXTURE_Y]);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glUniform1i(_uniformSamplers[SAMPLER_Y], TEXTURE_Y);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _textures[TEXTURE_U]);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glUniform1i(_uniformSamplers[SAMPLER_U], TEXTURE_U);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _textures[TEXTURE_V]);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glUniform1i(_uniformSamplers[SAMPLER_V], TEXTURE_V);
```

Although, like I said the playback seems to perform pretty well, I would like to try to fix those warnings. I tried several things without success. The only way I was able to remove them was by calling `glGenTextures(NUM_TEXTURES, _textures)/glDeleteTextures(NUM_TEXTURES, _textures)` at the beginning/ending of my callback but I don't think that is the right way.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first warning on your list can sometimes be a false positive in Instruments, so it may not be a real issue at all. However, it may indicate that you haven't properly cleared out the previous state of the framebuffer, so you could check to make sure that you don't also have a depth buffer that needs to be cleared in addition to your `GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT`.

The other two are simply telling you that it's taking a while to upload your image data via `glTexImage2D()` on each frame. If you're doing this on iOS 5.0, you could look at using texture caches to speed this upload process (`CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreate()` and friends). They might help you squeeze out a little extra performance.

Comment: Thank you! I will take a look at CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreate(). Do you think those are warning that is worth to worry about? Also, I'm wondering why the warnings go away when I do glGenTextures(NUM_TEXTURES, _textures)/glDeleteTextures(NUM_TEXTURES, _textures at the beginning/ending of each drawing?

Comment: @Glauco - These aren't like compiler warnings, they're just suggestions for areas of potential performance improvements. Like I said, sometimes they can be false positives and not much of an issue at all. If your performance is good and you don't feel the need to tweak it further, you might be safe in ignoring these.