# How to render view into image faster?

Tags: ios, ios6, uiview, core-graphics, calayer

I'm making magnifier app, which allows an user touch the screen and move his finger, there will be a magnifier with his finger path. I implement it with take a screenshot and assign the image to magnifier image view, as following:

```
    CGSize imageSize = frame.size;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0.0);
    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextScaleCTM(c, scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
    CGContextConcatCTM(c, CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-frame.origin.x, -frame.origin.y));
    [self.layer renderInContext:c];
    UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return screenshot;
```

the problem is that `self.layer renderInContext` is slow, so user feel not smooth when he is moving his finger. and I tried to run `self.layer renderInContext` in other thread, however, it makes the magnifier image looked weird because the image in magnifier showed delay.

is there any better way to render view into image? does `renderInContext:` use GPU?

Comment: In answer to your question, according to [Polishing Your User Interface Rotations](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=240), `renderInContext` is performed in CPU.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

No. In iOS6, renderInContext: is the only way. It is slow. It uses the CPU.

### Ways to render UIKit content

#### renderInContext:

```
[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
```

- Requires iOS 2.0. [It runs in the CPU](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=240).
- It doesn't capture views with non-affine transforms, OpenGL, or video content.
- If an animation is running, you can have the option of capturing:

  - `view.layer`, which captures the final frame of the animation.
  - `view.presentationLayer`, which captures the current frame of the animation .

#### snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:

```
UIView *snapshot = [view snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:YES];
```

- Requires iOS 7.
- It is the fastest method.
- The view `contents` are immutable. Not good if you want to apply an effect.
- It captures all content types (UIKit, OpenGL, or video).

#### resizableSnapshotViewFromRect:afterScreenUpdates:withCapInsets

```
[view resizableSnapshotViewFromRect:rect afterScreenUpdates:YES withCapInsets:edgeInsets]
```

- Requires iOS 7.
- Same as `snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:` but with resizable insets. `content` is also immutable.

#### drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:

```
[view drawViewHierarchyInRect:rect afterScreenUpdates:YES];
```

- Requires iOS 7.
- It draws in the current context.
- According to session 226 it is faster than `renderInContext:`.

See WWDC 2013 Session [226 Implementing Engaging UI on iOS](http://asciiwwdc.com/2013/sessions/226?q=UISnapshotting) about the new snapshotting APIs.

---

If it is any help, here is some code to discard capture attempts while one is still running.

This throttles block execution to one at a time, and discards others. From [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944050).

```
dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(1);
dispatch_queue_t renderQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.throttling.queue", NULL);

- (void) capture {
    if (dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW) == 0) {
        dispatch_async(renderQueue, ^{
            // capture
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
        });
    }
}
```

What is this doing?

- Create a semaphore for one (1) resource.
- Create a serial queue.
- `DISPATCH_TIME_NOW` means the timeout is none, so it returns non zero immediately on red light. Thus, not executing the if content.
- If green light, run the block asynchronously, and set green light again.

Comment: instead of renderInContext, is there any way to do it?

Comment: No. If it is any help, try rasterizing the layer you are about to render and use a serial queue with a semaphore so it does one renderInContext: at a time. I'm posting some code above. But again, `renderInContext:` is the only way to capture UIKit content, and it is slow.

Comment: Just noting that the original question asked about rendering into an image, and this answer shows rendering into a view.

Comment: renderInContext and drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates: draw into a context that you can turn into an UIImage with UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(). You can also use drawViewHierarchyInRect to draw the view to the context. I'll try to add some sample code when I have the time.

Comment: does snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates require the layer to actually have been visible to capture anything?  I would like to snapshot the contents of a view without ever actually having drawn it to the screen.

Comment: Just to note that `snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:` will not work if you plan to get an image from the resulting UIView: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203682/uiimage-from-a-uiview-created-with-snapshotviewafterscreenupdates.

Comment: Im using "drawViewHierarchyInRect" to get image from a UIWebview,but im always getting blank white image,pls assist me to fix this issue

Comment: Although not officially deprecated, renderInContext is returning a solid gray image in my app on the latest hardware (iPhone 7 and 9.7" iPad Pro). I reported this to Apple as bug 28804475, but haven't received a reply.