# UIImage from a UIView created with snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:

Tags: uiview, ios7, uiimage, screenshot, snapshot

Is it possible to get a UIImage from a UIView created with `snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates`?

A UIView returned from `snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates` looks fine when added as a subview, but the following produces a black image:

```
UIView *snapshotView = [someView snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:YES]; 
UIImage *snapshotImage = [self imageFromView:snapshotView]; 

- (UIImage *)imageFromView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, YES, 0.0);
    // [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()]; // <- same result...
    [view drawViewHierarchyInRect:view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:NO];
    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return img;
}
```

It is of course possible to get the image without relying on `snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates`:

```
UIImage *snapshotImage = [self imageFromView:someView];
```

Unfortunately, when capturing a complex view, `drawViewHierarchyInRect` can't match the speed of `snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates`. I was hoping that it would be faster to get the `UIImage` from a view created by `snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates`, is this possible?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The answer seems to be **NO** and Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:) implicitly confirms this:

> If you want to apply a graphical effect, such as blur, to a snapshot, use the `drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:` method
>   instead.

It's worth noting that the *Implementing Engaging UI on iOS* session from WWDC13 lists `snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates` as the fastest method, but uses `drawViewHierarchyInRect` in the example code.

Comment: I think the reason this is not working is that the view returned by snapshot is actually NOT a full fledged view.  If you step through the debugger, you will see that it's type is '_UIReplicantView'.  This makes me think that it is just an optimized copy of the other view and doesn't have the same 'layer' characteristics of a 'full' UIView...

Comment: Thanks @MobileVet, that's good to know. Still frustrating that there's no way to get the pixels from a feature that is all about quick screen capture...

Comment: Apple confirms that this is not possible. See: http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=8993&start=10

Comment: @CarlosGuzman thanks for adding that link, it contains some helpful explanations.

Comment: Very frustrating. drawViewHierarchyInRect is too slow and uses too much CPU. You'd think there'd be a simple way to get an OpenGL texture or at least a CVPixelBufferRef from a view since it's all OpenGL underneath anyway...