# View to image doesn't work on device

Tags: device, snapshot

I use the following code to turn an `UIView` in an `UIImage`.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, 0.0f);
[self drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
UIImage *snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Works fine on te simulator. When I check `snapshotImage` in the console after the breakpoint was hit, it shows the image. Unfortunately, this code doesn't work on a device. It returns a transparent image with the right size. Tested on a iPhone 5 and a iPhone 5S (so no 64-bit problem). Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Turned out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203682/uiimage-from-a-uiview-created-with-snapshotviewafterscreenupdates) it is not possible to first create a snapshot with `snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:` and then turn it into a `UIImage`. Instead of using the snapshot of `self.view` I'm using `self.view` directly now.