# Screen Capture a UIView that has Camera function in it

Tags: ios, objective-c, avcapturesession

I am trying to screen capture a view that has APPLCameraViewContoller in it. For some reason when it gets saved to camera roll no mater what I do what the camera is looking at does not get captured only the UIView with labels does so it is a black background with the labels. I want to have the labels on top of the Camera View. Any suggestions or examples on how to go about this. Here is the screen capture .m which I am assuming is the reason why this is happening.

```
@interface ASScreenRecorder()
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAssetWriter *videoWriter;
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAssetWriterInput *videoWriterInput;
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor   *avAdaptor;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CADisplayLink *displayLink;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *outputBufferPoolAuxAttributes;
@property (nonatomic) CFTimeInterval firstTimeStamp;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isRecording;
@end

@implementation ASScreenRecorder
{
dispatch_queue_t _render_queue;
dispatch_queue_t _append_pixelBuffer_queue;
dispatch_semaphore_t _frameRenderingSemaphore;
dispatch_semaphore_t _pixelAppendSemaphore;

CGSize _viewSize;
CGFloat _scale;

CGColorSpaceRef _rgbColorSpace;
CVPixelBufferPoolRef _outputBufferPool;
}

#pragma mark - initializers

+ (instancetype)sharedInstance {
static dispatch_once_t once;
static ASScreenRecorder *sharedInstance;
dispatch_once(&once, ^{
    sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
});
return sharedInstance;
}

- (instancetype)init
{
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    _viewSize = [UIApplication  sharedApplication].delegate.window.bounds.size;
    _scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    // record half size resolution for retina iPads
    if ((UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) && _scale > 1)   {
        _scale = 1.0;
    }
    _isRecording = NO;

    _append_pixelBuffer_queue =   dispatch_queue_create("ASScreenRecorder.append_queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    _render_queue = dispatch_queue_create("ASScreenRecorder.render_queue",   DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    dispatch_set_target_queue(_render_queue, dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0));
    _frameRenderingSemaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(1);
    _pixelAppendSemaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(1);
}
return self;
}

#pragma mark - public

- (void)setVideoURL:(NSURL *)videoURL
{
NSAssert(!_isRecording, @"videoURL can not be changed whilst recording is in progress");
_videoURL = videoURL;
}

- (BOOL)startRecording
{
if (!_isRecording) {
    [self setUpWriter];
    _isRecording = (_videoWriter.status == AVAssetWriterStatusWriting);
    _displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(writeVideoFrame)];
    [_displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}
return _isRecording;
}

- (void)stopRecordingWithCompletion:(VideoCompletionBlock)completionBlock;
{
if (_isRecording) {
    _isRecording = NO;
    [_displayLink removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
    [self completeRecordingSession:completionBlock];
}
}

#pragma mark - private

-(void)setUpWriter
{
_rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

NSDictionary *bufferAttributes = @{(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey :   @(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA),
                                    (id)kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey : @YES,
                                   (id)kCVPixelBufferWidthKey :  @(_viewSize.width * _scale),
                                   (id)kCVPixelBufferHeightKey : @(_viewSize.height * _scale),
                                   (id)kCVPixelBufferBytesPerRowAlignmentKey  : @(_viewSize.width * _scale * 4)
                                   };

_outputBufferPool = NULL;
CVPixelBufferPoolCreate(NULL, NULL, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)(bufferAttributes), &_outputBufferPool);


NSError* error = nil;
_videoWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:self.videoURL ?: [self tempFileURL]
                                         fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
                                            error:&error];
NSParameterAssert(_videoWriter);

NSInteger pixelNumber = _viewSize.width * _viewSize.height * _scale;
NSDictionary* videoCompression = @{AVVideoAverageBitRateKey: @(pixelNumber * 11.4)};

NSDictionary* videoSettings = @{AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecH264,
                                AVVideoWidthKey: [NSNumber numberWithInt:_viewSize.width*_scale],
                                AVVideoHeightKey: [NSNumber numberWithInt:_viewSize.height*_scale],
                                AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey: videoCompression};

_videoWriterInput = [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo outputSettings:videoSettings];
NSParameterAssert(_videoWriterInput);

_videoWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;
_videoWriterInput.transform = [self videoTransformForDeviceOrientation];

_avAdaptor = [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:_videoWriterInput sourcePixelBufferAttributes:nil];

[_videoWriter addInput:_videoWriterInput];

[_videoWriter startWriting];
[_videoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:CMTimeMake(0, 1000)];
}

- (CGAffineTransform)videoTransformForDeviceOrientation
{
CGAffineTransform videoTransform;
switch ([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation) {
    case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
        videoTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2);
        break;
    case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
        videoTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
        break;
    case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
        videoTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
        break;
    default:
        videoTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
}
return videoTransform;
}

- (NSURL*)tempFileURL
{
NSString *outputPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tmp/screenCapture.mp4"];
[self removeTempFilePath:outputPath];
return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:outputPath];
}

- (void)removeTempFilePath:(NSString*)filePath
{
NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
    NSError* error;
    if ([fileManager removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error] == NO) {
        NSLog(@"Could not delete old recording:%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
}

- (void)completeRecordingSession:(VideoCompletionBlock)completionBlock;
{
dispatch_async(_render_queue, ^{
    dispatch_sync(_append_pixelBuffer_queue, ^{

        [_videoWriterInput markAsFinished];
        [_videoWriter finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:^{

            void (^completion)(void) = ^() {
                [self cleanup];
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    if (completionBlock) completionBlock();
                });
            };

            if (self.videoURL) {
                completion();
            } else {
                ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
                [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:_videoWriter.outputURL completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
                    if (error) {
                        NSLog(@"Error copying video to camera roll:%@",   [error localizedDescription]);
                    } else {
                        [self  removeTempFilePath:_videoWriter.outputURL.path];
                        completion();
                    }
                }];
            }
        }];
    });
});
}

- (void)cleanup
{
self.avAdaptor = nil;
self.videoWriterInput = nil;
self.videoWriter = nil;
self.firstTimeStamp = 0;
self.outputBufferPoolAuxAttributes = nil;
CGColorSpaceRelease(_rgbColorSpace);
CVPixelBufferPoolRelease(_outputBufferPool);
}

- (void)writeVideoFrame
{
// throttle the number of frames to prevent meltdown
// technique gleaned from Brad Larson's answer here:   http://stackoverflow.com/a/5956119
if (dispatch_semaphore_wait(_frameRenderingSemaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW) != 0) {
    return;
}
dispatch_async(_render_queue, ^{
    if (![_videoWriterInput isReadyForMoreMediaData]) return;

    if (!self.firstTimeStamp) {
        self.firstTimeStamp = _displayLink.timestamp;
    }
    CFTimeInterval elapsed = (_displayLink.timestamp - self.firstTimeStamp);
    CMTime time = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(elapsed, 1000);

    CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = NULL;
    CGContextRef bitmapContext = [self createPixelBufferAndBitmapContext:&pixelBuffer];

    if (self.delegate) {
        [self.delegate writeBackgroundFrameInContext:&bitmapContext];
    }
    // draw each window into the context (other windows include UIKeyboard, UIAlert)
    // FIX: UIKeyboard is currently only rendered correctly in portrait orientation
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIGraphicsPushContext(bitmapContext); {
            for (UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) {
                [window drawViewHierarchyInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, _viewSize.width, _viewSize.height) afterScreenUpdates:NO];
            }
        } UIGraphicsPopContext();
    });

    // append pixelBuffer on a async dispatch_queue, the next frame is rendered whilst this one appends
    // must not overwhelm the queue with pixelBuffers, therefore:
    // check if _append_pixelBuffer_queue is ready
    // if it’s not ready, release pixelBuffer and bitmapContext
    if (dispatch_semaphore_wait(_pixelAppendSemaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW) == 0) {
        dispatch_async(_append_pixelBuffer_queue, ^{
            BOOL success = [_avAdaptor appendPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer withPresentationTime:time];
            if (!success) {
                NSLog(@"Warning: Unable to write buffer to video");
            }
            CGContextRelease(bitmapContext);
            CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);
            CVPixelBufferRelease(pixelBuffer);

            dispatch_semaphore_signal(_pixelAppendSemaphore);
        });
    } else {
        CGContextRelease(bitmapContext);
        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);
        CVPixelBufferRelease(pixelBuffer);
    }

    dispatch_semaphore_signal(_frameRenderingSemaphore);
});
}

 - (CGContextRef)createPixelBufferAndBitmapContext:(CVPixelBufferRef *)pixelBuffer
{
CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer(NULL, _outputBufferPool, pixelBuffer);
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(*pixelBuffer, 0);

CGContextRef bitmapContext = NULL;
bitmapContext =   CGBitmapContextCreate(CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(*pixelBuffer),
                                      CVPixelBufferGetWidth(*pixelBuffer),
                                      CVPixelBufferGetHeight(*pixelBuffer),
                                      8,   CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(*pixelBuffer), _rgbColorSpace,
                                      kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little |   kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst
                                      );
CGContextScaleCTM(bitmapContext, _scale, _scale);
CGAffineTransform flipVertical = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0,   _viewSize.height);
CGContextConcatCTM(bitmapContext, flipVertical);

return bitmapContext;
}
```

I would be more than happy to provide my full source code to anyone who could tackle something like this because posting multiple .m's on this would take up a lot of space.
[image: What I want it to look like]

[image: What it looks like when I save it]

Comment: screen capture doesnt capture the content on calayer. As you initiate the camera sesison on a layer but not on a view, you cant capture the camera session. Unless you have to take a picture and then draw it on the view and then take a snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's similar for you. But I've been using ASScreenRecorder to record an ARSceneView, and that has been going fine. Have a look at the following link, you can provide it a view to render and it records and provides an output URL link. You might have to make a small edit to the class to get the StopRecording Function's completion handler to work.

https://github.com/alskipp/ASScreenRecorder