# Screen recording of iPhone while playing a video

Tags: ios, core-animation, avplayer, ios-camera, uiviewanimation-curve

In my project I have to add a book page flip animation, and in this book on the right side page a video will play. Once the first video will complete the page will turn like as book page and the second video will play on the next right side page and so on. Now I have to save all this things as a a video which can be downloaded, so that When the downloaded video get played from gallery it looks same as i am playing in my app. Right now I am recording the device's screen and saving it in server for download. All the things is ok except the video player. In the video that is I am recording, the portion where all the video is playing(on the right side page of the book) is not getting recorded. 
I am using the bellow code to record the screen. If any one of you have other idea to do the same thing, please share with me or if need to change my code please suggest that. Thanks is advance.

```
//  ASScreenRecorder.h
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    typedef void (^VideoCompletionBlock)(void);
    @protocol ASScreenRecorderDelegate;

    @interface ASScreenRecorder : NSObject
    @property (nonatomic, readonly) BOOL isRecording;

    @property (nonatomic, weak) id <ASScreenRecorderDelegate> delegate;

    // if saveURL is nil, video will be saved into camera roll
    // this property can not be changed whilst recording is in progress
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSURL *videoURL;

    + (instancetype)sharedInstance;
    - (BOOL)startRecording;
    - (void)stopRecordingWithCompletion:(VideoCompletionBlock)completionBlock;
    @end


    // If your view contains an AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer or an openGL view
    // you'll need to write that data into the CGContextRef yourself.
    // In the viewcontroller responsible for the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer / openGL view
    // set yourself as the delegate for ASScreenRecorder.
    // [ASScreenRecorder sharedInstance].delegate = self
    // Then implement 'writeBackgroundFrameInContext:(CGContextRef*)contextRef'
    // use 'CGContextDrawImage' to draw your view into the provided CGContextRef
    @protocol ASScreenRecorderDelegate <NSObject>
    - (void)writeBackgroundFrameInContext:(CGContextRef*)contextRef;
    @end



//  ASScreenRecorder.m
//  ScreenRecorder
//
//  Created by Alan Skipp on 23/04/2014.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Alan Skipp. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ASScreenRecorder.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>

@interface ASScreenRecorder()
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAssetWriter *videoWriter;
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAssetWriterInput *videoWriterInput;
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor *avAdaptor;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CADisplayLink *displayLink;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *outputBufferPoolAuxAttributes;
@property (nonatomic) CFTimeInterval firstTimeStamp;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isRecording;
@end

@implementation ASScreenRecorder
{
    dispatch_queue_t _render_queue;
    dispatch_queue_t _append_pixelBuffer_queue;
    dispatch_semaphore_t _frameRenderingSemaphore;
    dispatch_semaphore_t _pixelAppendSemaphore;

    CGSize _viewSize;
    CGFloat _scale;

    CGColorSpaceRef _rgbColorSpace;
    CVPixelBufferPoolRef _outputBufferPool;
}

#pragma mark - initializers

+ (instancetype)sharedInstance {
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static ASScreenRecorder *sharedInstance;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _viewSize = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.bounds.size;
        _scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
        // record half size resolution for retina iPads
        if ((UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) && _scale > 1) {
            _scale = 1.0;
        }
        _isRecording = NO;

        _append_pixelBuffer_queue = dispatch_queue_create("ASScreenRecorder.append_queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
        _render_queue = dispatch_queue_create("ASScreenRecorder.render_queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
        dispatch_set_target_queue(_render_queue, dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0));
        _frameRenderingSemaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(1);
        _pixelAppendSemaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(1);
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - public

- (void)setVideoURL:(NSURL *)videoURL
{
    NSAssert(!_isRecording, @"videoURL can not be changed whilst recording is in progress");
    _videoURL = videoURL;
}

- (BOOL)startRecording
{
    if (!_isRecording) {
        [self setUpWriter];
        _isRecording = (_videoWriter.status == AVAssetWriterStatusWriting);
        _displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(writeVideoFrame)];
        [_displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
    }
    return _isRecording;
}

- (void)stopRecordingWithCompletion:(VideoCompletionBlock)completionBlock;
{
    if (_isRecording) {
        _isRecording = NO;
        [_displayLink removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
        [self completeRecordingSession:completionBlock];
    }
}

#pragma mark - private

-(void)setUpWriter
{
    _rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    NSDictionary *bufferAttributes = @{(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey : @(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA),
                                       (id)kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey : @YES,
                                       (id)kCVPixelBufferWidthKey : @(_viewSize.width * _scale),
                                       (id)kCVPixelBufferHeightKey : @(_viewSize.height * _scale),
                                       (id)kCVPixelBufferBytesPerRowAlignmentKey : @(_viewSize.width * _scale * 4)
                                       };

    _outputBufferPool = NULL;
    CVPixelBufferPoolCreate(NULL, NULL, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)(bufferAttributes), &_outputBufferPool);


    NSError* error = nil;
    _videoWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:self.videoURL ?: [self tempFileURL]
                                             fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
                                                error:&error];
    NSParameterAssert(_videoWriter);

    NSInteger pixelNumber = _viewSize.width * _viewSize.height * _scale;
    NSDictionary* videoCompression = @{AVVideoAverageBitRateKey: @(pixelNumber * 11.4)};

    NSDictionary* videoSettings = @{AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecH264,
                                    AVVideoWidthKey: [NSNumber numberWithInt:_viewSize.width*_scale],
                                    AVVideoHeightKey: [NSNumber numberWithInt:_viewSize.height*_scale],
                                    AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey: videoCompression};

    _videoWriterInput = [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo outputSettings:videoSettings];
    NSParameterAssert(_videoWriterInput);

    _videoWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;
    _videoWriterInput.transform = [self videoTransformForDeviceOrientation];

    _avAdaptor = [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:_videoWriterInput sourcePixelBufferAttributes:nil];

    [_videoWriter addInput:_videoWriterInput];

    [_videoWriter startWriting];
    [_videoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:CMTimeMake(0, 1000)];
}

- (CGAffineTransform)videoTransformForDeviceOrientation
{
    CGAffineTransform videoTransform;
    switch ([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation) {
        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            videoTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2);
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            videoTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            videoTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
            break;
        default:
            videoTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    }
    return videoTransform;
}

- (NSURL*)tempFileURL
{
    NSString *outputPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tmp/screenCapture.mp4"];
    [self removeTempFilePath:outputPath];
    return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:outputPath];
}

- (void)removeTempFilePath:(NSString*)filePath
{
    NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
        NSError* error;
        if ([fileManager removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error] == NO) {
            NSLog(@"Could not delete old recording:%@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }
}

- (void)completeRecordingSession:(VideoCompletionBlock)completionBlock;
{
    dispatch_async(_render_queue, ^{
        dispatch_sync(_append_pixelBuffer_queue, ^{

            [_videoWriterInput markAsFinished];
            [_videoWriter finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:^{

                void (^completion)(void) = ^() {
                    [self cleanup];
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        if (completionBlock) completionBlock();
                    });
                };

                if (self.videoURL) {
                    completion();
                } else {
                    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
                    [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:_videoWriter.outputURL completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
                        if (error) {
                            NSLog(@"Error copying video to camera roll:%@", [error localizedDescription]);
                        } else {
                            [self removeTempFilePath:_videoWriter.outputURL.path];
                            completion();
                        }
                    }];
                }
            }];
        });
    });
}

- (void)cleanup
{
    self.avAdaptor = nil;
    self.videoWriterInput = nil;
    self.videoWriter = nil;
    self.firstTimeStamp = 0;
    self.outputBufferPoolAuxAttributes = nil;
    CGColorSpaceRelease(_rgbColorSpace);
    CVPixelBufferPoolRelease(_outputBufferPool);
}

- (void)writeVideoFrame
{
    // throttle the number of frames to prevent meltdown
    // technique gleaned from Brad Larson's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5956119
    if (dispatch_semaphore_wait(_frameRenderingSemaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW) != 0) {
        return;
    }
    dispatch_async(_render_queue, ^{
        if (![_videoWriterInput isReadyForMoreMediaData]) return;

        if (!self.firstTimeStamp) {
            self.firstTimeStamp = _displayLink.timestamp;
        }
        CFTimeInterval elapsed = (_displayLink.timestamp - self.firstTimeStamp);
        CMTime time = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(elapsed, 1000);

        CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = NULL;
        CGContextRef bitmapContext = [self createPixelBufferAndBitmapContext:&pixelBuffer];

        if (self.delegate) {
            [self.delegate writeBackgroundFrameInContext:&bitmapContext];
        }
        // draw each window into the context (other windows include UIKeyboard, UIAlert)
        // FIX: UIKeyboard is currently only rendered correctly in portrait orientation
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIGraphicsPushContext(bitmapContext); {
                for (UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) {
                    [window drawViewHierarchyInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, _viewSize.width, _viewSize.height) afterScreenUpdates:NO];
                }
            } UIGraphicsPopContext();
        });

        // append pixelBuffer on a async dispatch_queue, the next frame is rendered whilst this one appends
        // must not overwhelm the queue with pixelBuffers, therefore:
        // check if _append_pixelBuffer_queue is ready
        // if it’s not ready, release pixelBuffer and bitmapContext
        if (dispatch_semaphore_wait(_pixelAppendSemaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW) == 0) {
            dispatch_async(_append_pixelBuffer_queue, ^{
                BOOL success = [_avAdaptor appendPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer withPresentationTime:time];
                if (!success) {
                    NSLog(@"Warning: Unable to write buffer to video");
                }
                CGContextRelease(bitmapContext);
                CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);
                CVPixelBufferRelease(pixelBuffer);

                dispatch_semaphore_signal(_pixelAppendSemaphore);
            });
        } else {
            CGContextRelease(bitmapContext);
            CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);
            CVPixelBufferRelease(pixelBuffer);
        }

        dispatch_semaphore_signal(_frameRenderingSemaphore);
    });
}

- (CGContextRef)createPixelBufferAndBitmapContext:(CVPixelBufferRef *)pixelBuffer
{
    CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer(NULL, _outputBufferPool, pixelBuffer);
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(*pixelBuffer, 0);

    CGContextRef bitmapContext = NULL;
    bitmapContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(*pixelBuffer),
                                          CVPixelBufferGetWidth(*pixelBuffer),
                                          CVPixelBufferGetHeight(*pixelBuffer),
                                          8, CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(*pixelBuffer), _rgbColorSpace,
                                          kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst
                                          );
    CGContextScaleCTM(bitmapContext, _scale, _scale);
    CGAffineTransform flipVertical = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, _viewSize.height);
    CGContextConcatCTM(bitmapContext, flipVertical);

    return bitmapContext;
}

@end
```

Comment: Gobinda : Any solution ?

Answer (score -1):

@Gobinda this code works in my case. You need to specify frame if you want to record portion of window. In init method viewSize is defined as window size. So you need to change viewSize as your video frame.