# uiscrollview and cocos2d sticking

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I am having trouble using a uiscrollview with cocos2d.

I followed this:
http://bitbattalion.com/2011/09/uikit-uiscrollview-and-cocos2d/

Then, I completed it with this:
[Animation in OpenGL ES view freezes when UIScrollView is dragged on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876488/animation-in-opengl-es-view-freezes-when-uiscrollview-is-dragged-on-iphone)

It seems to work fine on the simulator but gets weird on the iPod: it is very jerky and does not keep scrolling when you flick it.  This behavior goes away after you flick it around a while and sometimes it starts up fine.

I am using iOS 5.1 and cocos2d 2.x.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the animation interval to half of your current frame rate while displaying the scroll view:

```
CCDirector* director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
director.animationInterval = director.animationInterval * 2.0f;
```

Then later when you are no longer displaying the scroll view, reset it back to the original interval.

I also found that in my case the second link (OpenGL freezes) didn't work. I had to actually use GCD and a semaphore to in cocos2d's main rendering method to allow Cocoa enough time to animate and render its own stuff.

Comment: Wow! That did it.  Thanks a lot buddy.  But why did it not work in your situation, out of curiosity?

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185720/uitableview-and-cocos2d/15185848#15185848