# Scrollview scrolling causing UI deadlock. Change runloop mode?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a system multithreaded across Swift, C++ and Objective-C.

I've noticed that when scrolling a scrollview, the UI can totally deadlock. OpenGL is still rendering and updating correctly and the audio thread is still running, but I cannot interact with the UI.

This only happens when scrolling the scrollview, especially when decelerating.

Is there a way to change the runloop mode for the scrollview tracking or a different way to fix this issue?

I profiled with Time Profiler to check for thread waiting indicators and I cannot determine what is causing the deadlock.

> EDIT:

After additional testing, it looks like collectionviews and tableviews are also causing the deadlock.

How can this be debugged?

Comment: What are you trying to display in your scroll view?

Comment: In the scroll view I have a number of UIView subviews. The deadlock is being caused in any scrollview, the tableviews and the collection views too. All displaying custom cells, nothing that could specifically cause the deadlock.

Comment: I found that there was a severe lag in my tableview scrolling when I was setting `tableview.estimatedRowHeight` to a large value, lowering that solved my issues. As for your scrollview, is the memory okay? No leaks?

Comment: Have you had a look at this answer? Seems similar to the issues you have experiencing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876488/animation-in-opengl-es-view-freezes-when-uiscrollview-is-dragged-on-iphone

Comment: Thanks for the link, its kind of reverse to what I am experiencing, but put me on the right path. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who might come across the same issue.

I had C++ code that was calling a completion block into Swift. The completion block was `dispatch_async`ing back to the main thread at a high rate, in order for the `setNeedsDisplay()` to trigger render updates on a `GLKView`.

This led to a UI deadlock only when a scrollview was scrolled.

I fixed this by using a `CADisplayLink` instead, which just calls `setNeedsDisplay()` on the `GLKView` if certain properties are true.