# CADisplayLink catches animation with delay

Tags: swift, uiview, core-animation, cashapelayer, cadisplaylink

Trying to reproduce behaviour described in [this article](https://medium.com/@gontovnik/elastic-view-animation-or-how-i-built-dgelasticpulltorefresh-269a3ba8636e). Line by line. Everything works well but the last step...

The problem is: I unpause `CADisplayLink` just before calling `UIView.animate` and expect the unpaused `CADisplayLink` to call the attached selector on main thread during animation. It does work, but it starts to call the attached selector with a half a second delay.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Nope, testing on device. Simulator was just used to make a gif via QuickTime.

Comment: Okay, I'll try! Thanks (:

Comment: I have found a solution. Replacing RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode with RunLoopMode.commonModes solved the issue. But I am far from understanding the difference between these two modes and why they have such a different impact... ):

Comment: Nevertheless you should answer your own question and, in 2 days, accept your own answer. Well done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you've chosen a wrong RunLoopMode. With RunLoopMode.commonModes it works like a charm. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524347/cadisplaylink-stops-updating-when-uiscrollview-scrolled/3118153#3118153) for a detailed answer.