# Any interaction with the screen locks animation

Tags: ios, uiimageview, core-graphics

I have a UIView that sets a timer and each firing it generates a UIImage on a background queue (priority `.userInitiated`), and when finished (measured to take between 1-2 milliseconds, it pushes to the main queue and updates a UIImageView's image.

This creates a smooth animation effect (e.g. if the Timer is configured to fire 30 times per second).  Touching the screen however either slows down or completely shuts down the updating.  I removed my overrides of touchesBegan,Moved,Ended and any GestureRecognizers to ensure that I wasn't doing anything expensive.  Simply touching the screen (especially dragging quickly) prevents the UI updating.

I watched [this](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012/211/) and googled as many SO posts as I can but I'm completely stuck on this.

Here is a reproduction of the problem.  Run the app and it will display a stripped down rendering of a basic project.  From there, you can drag/touch the screen and notice the frames will either slow down to a crawl or completely stop.

[Github Repro](https://github.com/AlexanderBollbach/ReproduceAnimationBug)

Comment: Personally I'd use a [`CADisplayLink`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cadisplaylink), but you need to [configure it so it's not affected by scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524347/cadisplaylink-stops-updating-when-uiscrollview-scrolled)

Comment: sure, but i'm still running the intensive processing on a background queue and simply updating the UIImageView's image on the main queue.  apple even suggests one can use both a Timer and a DisplayLink to do real time animating like this.  I'll try substitution a DisplayLink but using a Timer specifically should not be the bottleneck.

Comment: As I understand it, both (by default) `CADisplayLink` and `Timer` run on the main `runLoop`, so any UI interaction could "stall" them - I might be over simplifying this though

Comment: well, something relevant here is that I added a print statement in the line that pushes to the main queue and updates the UIImageView.  when i start dragging, its stilled fired.  So the Timer keeps firing, the processing is succeeding while I'm dragging, I just don't see the results.  So the problem appears to be "downstream" of the timer firing and rendering.

Comment: Possibly because the "paint" cycles are suspended? I was told in passing about `Timer` running on the main run loop and how would be affected by scrolling :/

Comment: what are "paint" cycles and how do i unsuspend them lol

Comment: i'm not "scrolling" fwiw.  no scroll views or gesture recognizers.  not even touchesMoved.  just dragging on the screen with no hooks or handlers.  the UIView is a plain view with an embedded UImageView.

Comment: We're all just discussing theoretical possibilities, without a suitable runnable example, it would be difficult (for me, with my limited experience) to make any "real" suggestion, beyond making use of a `CADisplayLink`, which I've switched to using instead of `Timer` so I configure it's run loop